# DRYing up Rails Views with Nested Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, nested-resources

What is your solution to the problem if you have a model that is both not-nested and nested, such as products:

> a "Product" can belong_to say an "Event", and a Product can also just be independent.

This means I can have routes like this:

```
map.resources :products # /products
map.resources :events do |event|
  event.resources :products # /events/1/products
end
```

How do you handle that in your views properly?

*Note: this is for an admin panel.  I want to be able to have a "Create Event" page, with a side panel for creating tickets (Product), forms, and checking who's rsvp'd.  So you'd click on the "Event Tickets" side panel button, and it'd take you to `/events/my-new-event/tickets`.  But there's also a root "Products" tab for the admin panel, which could list tickets and other random products.  The 'tickets' and 'products' views look 90% the same, but the tickets will have some info about the event it belongs to.*

It seems like I'd have to have views like this:

- products/index.haml
- products/show.haml
- events/products/index.haml
- events/products/show.haml

But that doesn't seem DRY.  Or I could have conditionals checking to see if the product had an Event (`@product.event.nil?`), but then the views would be hard to understand.

How do you deal with these situations?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to make separate admin controller with it's own views to administrate everything you want. And your customer's logic stayed in products contoller.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have good and clean solution for this problem. Usualy if views doesn't differ to much, I use single view and add some code like `@product.event.nil?`. You can always add some variable, or helper that will make this method shorter, on example `has_event?` - then your view will look cleaner. And use it in code like this:

```
<% if has_event? %>
  some html
<% end %>
```

or for single line:

```
<%= link_to 'Something special', foo_path if has_event? %>
```

On the other side, you can create few partials that are the same for both views, put them in some folder, on example `/shared/products/...` and render them from your views like this:

```
<%= render :partial => '/shared/products/info' %>
```

and so on.

But if they don't differ too much, I really would use `if` version.

Answer (score 0):

The views will be handled by the `ProductsController`. You can alter the logic in your controller depending on the nesting of the resource.

```
# app/controller/products_controller.rb
# ...some code...
def index
    @event = Event.find_by_id(params[:event_id]) if params[:event_id]
    @products = @event ? @event.products : Product.all
end
```

The view will be handled by the usual product view

```
# app/views/products/index.html.haml
- unless @products.blank?
    - @products.each do |product|
        %p= product.some_attribute
```